# Getting confuse of big picture of how to work in web project

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am trying to make a simple web app and I have completed making a register and login form. Now I have questions in my database and I wanted to display the question when the login is success and let the user to answer the question of the quiz .

But the problem is I am new to this and I am not getting how should I work with. If anyone would help me to guide a way to do it then I would be very greatful. 
[this is what i have done till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjpgV.png)

In `Quiz.java`

```
package com.quiz.model;

public class Quiz {
private int id;
private String question;
private String ans1;
private String ans2;
private String ans3;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
public String getAns1() {
    return ans1;
}
public void setAns1(String ans1) {
    this.ans1 = ans1;
}
public String getAns2() {
    return ans2;
}
public void setAns2(String ans2) {
    this.ans2 = ans2;
}
public String getAns3() {
    return ans3;
}
public void setAns3(String ans3) {
    this.ans3 = ans3;
}

}
```

QuizDaoImpl.java

```
public class QuizDaoImpl implements QuizDao {
private JdbcTemplate template;
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
public void setTemplate (JdbcTemplate template){
    this.template = template;
}
public List<Quiz> getQuestion() {
    List questionList = new ArrayList();
    String sql = "select * from question";
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    questionList = template.query(sql, new QuizRowMapper());
    return questionList;
}

public void insertQuestion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

QuizRowMapper.java

```
public class QuizRowMapper implements RowMapper{

public Quiz mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
    Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
    quiz.setId(rs.getInt("idquestion"));
    quiz.setQuestion(rs.getString("question"));
    quiz.setAns1(rs.getString("ans1"));
    quiz.setAns2(rs.getString("ans2"));
    quiz.setAns3(rs.getString("ans3"));
    return quiz;
}

}
```

HomePageController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

@Autowired
UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;
@RequestMapping("/register")
public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute user use){
    return new ModelAndView("register");

}
@RequestMapping("/insert")
public ModelAndView successMessage(@ModelAttribute user use){
    if(use != null){
        userDaoImpl.insertData(use);
    }
    return new ModelAndView("success" ,"name", use.getuName());
}
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView getUserList(@ModelAttribute user u){
    List<user> userList = userDaoImpl.getData();
    int len = userList.size();
    for(int i = 0;i< len ; i++){
        String userr = userList.get(i).getuName();
        if(userr.equals(u.getuName())){
            return new ModelAndView("quiz","name", u.getuName());
        }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("register");
}
@RequestMapping("/userSign")
public ModelAndView getUser(String name){

    List<user> userList = userDaoImpl.getData();
    int len = userList.size();
    for(int i = 0;i<len ; i++){
        String userr = userList.get(i).getuName();
        if(userr.equals(name)){
            return new ModelAndView("quiz","name", name);
        }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("error","name",name);
}
}
```